# Detect protocol availability in header file - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, ios10

I've downloaded the **XCode 8.2** `beta` and in order to fix a warning on a project I had to add the following `protocol` to a `header file`: [CAAnimationDelete](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/caanimationdelegate?language=objc) which is available only from iOS 10.

The problem is that by only adding the protocol the project didn't compile on `iOS versions` prior to 10, so I've added the following check:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED > __IPHONE_9_3
@interface CheckTest : UIView <CAAnimationDelegate>
#else
@interface CheckTest : UIView
#endif
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Looks good to me, however you probably want to use `== IPHONE_10` or similar, just in case there is an iOS 9.4 released (there won't be, but you know).  You will have to guard the delegate method implementation in a similar way, I assume...

Comment: @Droppy yeah, haven't thought about that! thanks a lot :) If you want post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your use of the guard macros is correct, with one minor change; you want to check if you are compiling for iOS 10+, so test for that in the macros:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface CheckTest : UIView <CAAnimationDelegate>
#else
@interface CheckTest : UIView
#endif
```

Don't forget to guard the `CAAnimationDelegate` method implementation using the same guard macros.

If you are doing this in lots of classes, then it might be more convenient to do this in your pre-compiled header:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10
#define VIEWS_USE_CAANIMATIONDELEGATE 1
#else
#define VIEWS_USE_CAANIMATIONDELEGATE 0
#endif
```

and change the guard macros to:

```
#if VIEWS_USE_CAANIMATIONDELEGATE
@interface CheckTest : UIView <CAAnimationDelegate>
#else
@interface CheckTest : UIView
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one typo, I just found on `Availability.h` that the code for iOS 10 is `__IPHONE_10_0`

Comment: For the record: this approach would normally break when you're compiling with an older iOS version, as `__IPHONE_10_0` is obviously being defined together with iOS 10. But surprisingly, that macro was already there in `CABase.h`. What usually happens is that you hardcode the value of the macro (`100000`) instead.

Comment: @PeterTutervai Yes, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way in the Objective-C header file.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL allowLocalNetworkTraffic API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.15), ios(14.2)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos, watchos) __WATCHOS_PROHIBITED;
```